# How to disable textfield autocorrect across the whole app?

Tags: cocoa, uitextfield

I have approximately 200 textfields within my app and going through interface builder and changing this feature would take me forever!  Is there a quicker way, perhaps in the appdelegate or something?

Comment: "@Justin is there another way?" well, i've suggested something. i've no idea if it will fit in with your existing app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do not try this without version control**

> @Justin is there another way?

200 nibs - mehh… you could try the following:

Create a subclass of `UITextField`. at some point in the source, disable autocorrect at some point in its implementation.

then replace the `UITextField` instances in your nibs with your subclass using `ibtool`

example:

```
ibtool --convert oldName-newName file.nib

              ibtool will change all classes with the exact
              name "oldName" to be named "newName" instead.
```

it's certainly not pretty, but it's the least tedious (read: least error prone) approach i can think of -- for a reasonably quick solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another ugly solution:

XIB files are in XML format. If all your textfields are in one XIB file, just right click on it, select **Open As > Source Code** to see XML data. Use Find/Replace to add proper key-value pairs.